# Create two columns from a datetime column

Tags: sql-server, datetime

So I have a question regarding creating two columns from a datetime column.

My example

```
  CREATE TABLE #Test (ID int, OK bit, Data datetime)
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (1,0,'Dec  1 2015 12:00AM')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (2,1,'Dec  2 2015 12:00AM')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (3,1,'Dec  3 2015 12:00AM')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (4,1,'Dec  4 2015 12:00AM')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (5,0,'Dec  5 2015 12:00AM')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (6,0,'Dec  6 2015 12:00AM')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (7,1,'Dec  7 2015 12:00AM')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (8,1,'Dec  8 2015 12:00AM')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (9,1,'Dec  9 2015 12:00AM')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (10,1,'Dec 10 2015 12:00AM')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (11,1,'Dec 11 2015 12:00AM')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (12,0,'Dec 12 2015 12:00AM')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (13,0,'Dec 13 2015 12:00AM')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (14,1,'Dec 14 2015 12:00AM')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (15,1,'Dec 15 2015 12:00AM')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (16,1,'Dec 16 2015 12:00AM')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (17,1,'Dec 17 2015 12:00AM')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (18,1,'Dec 18 2015 12:00AM')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (19,0,'Dec 19 2015 12:00AM')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (20,0,'Dec 20 2015 12:00AM')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (21,1,'Dec 21 2015 12:00AM')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (22,1,'Dec 22 2015 12:00AM')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (23,1,'Dec 23 2015 12:00AM')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (24,1,'Dec 24 2015 12:00AM')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (25,0,'Dec 25 2015 12:00AM')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (26,0,'Dec 26 2015 12:00AM')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (27,0,'Dec 27 2015 12:00AM')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (28,1,'Dec 28 2015 12:00AM')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (29,1,'Dec 29 2015 12:00AM')
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (30,1,'Dec 30 2015 12:00AM')
```

Which produce the following result

```
ID  OK  Data
--------------------
1   0   2015-12-01 00:00:00.000
2   1   2015-12-02 00:00:00.000
3   1   2015-12-03 00:00:00.000
4   1   2015-12-04 00:00:00.000
5   0   2015-12-05 00:00:00.000
6   0   2015-12-06 00:00:00.000
7   1   2015-12-07 00:00:00.000
8   1   2015-12-08 00:00:00.000
9   1   2015-12-09 00:00:00.000
10  1   2015-12-10 00:00:00.000
11  1   2015-12-11 00:00:00.000
12  0   2015-12-12 00:00:00.000
13  0   2015-12-13 00:00:00.000
14  1   2015-12-14 00:00:00.000
15  1   2015-12-15 00:00:00.000
16  1   2015-12-16 00:00:00.000
17  1   2015-12-17 00:00:00.000
18  1   2015-12-18 00:00:00.000
19  0   2015-12-19 00:00:00.000
20  0   2015-12-20 00:00:00.000
21  1   2015-12-21 00:00:00.000
22  1   2015-12-22 00:00:00.000
23  1   2015-12-23 00:00:00.000
24  1   2015-12-24 00:00:00.000
25  0   2015-12-25 00:00:00.000
26  0   2015-12-26 00:00:00.000
27  0   2015-12-27 00:00:00.000
28  1   2015-12-28 00:00:00.000
29  1   2015-12-29 00:00:00.000
30  1   2015-12-30 00:00:00.000
```

So my question is how can I create a two columns table without using a cursor or while.

The output should be. I know I can achieve this by using a cursor but It must be a more simple way. Any help?

```
    StartDate                 EndDate
    -----------------------   -----------------------
    2015-12-02 00:00:00.000 - 2015-12-04 00:00:00.000
    2015-12-07 00:00:00.000 - 2015-12-11 00:00:00.000
    2015-12-14 00:00:00.000 - 2015-12-18 00:00:00.000
    2015-12-21 00:00:00.000 - 2015-12-24 00:00:00.000
    2015-12-28 00:00:00.000 - 2015-12-30 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Is your question how to do it with a query, because when you say 'create a two columns table' then you could just do that instead of the single one?
And if a query - what's the logic used?

Comment: Yes, I would like to do it in a query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT MIN(Data) AS StartDate,
       MAX(Data) AS EndDate
FROM (
  SELECT ID, OK, Data,
         DATEADD(d, -1 * ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
                         (PARTITION BY OK ORDER BY ID), Data) AS grp
  FROM Test) AS t
WHERE OK = 1
GROUP BY grp
```

The query uses calculated field `grp` to identify islands of successive records having consecutive dates withing the same `OK` slice.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/97150/8)

Comment: Thank you! It is what I was looking for.